# Why can I find the first, but not the 2nd element with Xpath?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to build a test in Selenium Webdriver to check the values of 2 divs that have the same class name.

Eg, HTML:

```
<div class="prod-card">
  <div class="prices">
    <div class="price-wrap">
      From: 
      <div class="price">$9.99</div>
    </div>
    <div class="price-wrap">
      To: 
      <div class="price">$19.99</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've been trying to use Selenium's Xpath locator, but cannot seem to locate the 2nd div.

Eg, the below works:

```
let lowerPrice = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='price'][1]")).getText();
lowerPrice = lowerPrice.trim();
assert.equal(lowerPrice, expectations[i].lowerPrice);
```

But this does not work:

```
let higherPrice = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='price'][2]")).getText();
higherPrice = higherPrice.trim();
assert.equal(higherPrice, expectations[i].higherPrice);
```

I get the error `NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: //div[@class='price'][2]`

I don't know why this works fine when finding the first element, but not the 2nd.

Would anyone know why?

Comment: You can also use xpath like this `(//div[@class='price'])[1]` and `(//div[@class='price'])[2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will rather use

```
//div[@class='price-wrap'][1]/div[@class='price']
```

and

```
//div[@class='price-wrap'][2]/div[@class='price']
```

The reason is because the XPath expression `//div[@class='price'][2]` is attempting to select the second div element with the class name 'price' in the entire HTML document, rather than the second div element with the class name 'price' within a specific context.

Comment: Thanks, that worked but I'm a little confused as to why. In this case the 2nd `.price` would be the 2nd instance in the entire HTML document, so shouldn't that still work anyway?

Comment: let me put it like this your code would have work if you have it like this <div class="price-wrap">
        From: 
        <div class="price">$9.99</div>
        <div class="price">$9.99</div>
      </div>

Comment: really hard to explain exactly why. //div[@class='price'] returns the entire parent div of the two elements. If you want to index then try (//div[@class='price'])[1] or (//div[@class='price'])[2] . You would index the div and get first or the second price element